# turn on location services to allow to determine your location prompt in ios app doesn't allow user to select

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am working with swift 2.0 and I am stuck with this and probably there is something silly that I must not be implementing properly .. So , when I turn off the location Services in the settings of the phone , and open my app , the prompt that tells the user to turn on the location services keeps popping up and doesn't allow user to select any option.. Anyone has any idea why this might be happening ? If this has been already answered , kindly send me the link as I tried searching and didn't get any help. Let me know if any part of the code needs to be posted as well . Thank you in advance. this is how I have implemented ..

```
class LocationProcessHandler: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = LocationProcessHandler()

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    func startLocationUpdates() {




        NSLog("It entered the start location updates method of the location process handler")
    if ((CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == false) || (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied )) {

        NSLog("It Entered to create the managed app feedback ")
        let persist = Persistence()

                    let json: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            "IsLocationSettingsEnabled" : "\(0)",mdmiosagent_Constants.MESSAGETYPEKEY : mdmiosagent_Constants.LOCATIONMSGTYPEKEY,mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY : persist.getObject(mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY),"TimeStamp" : "\(self.toLocalTime())"
        ]
        let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.setObject(json, forKey: mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_FEEDBACK)
        userDefaults.synchronize()
        NSLog("The dict to be sent as managed app feedback is \(json)")
        do {
        let jsonData : NSData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            let wrapper = HttpWrapper()
            wrapper.silentPostData(serverurl: mdmiosagent_Constants.NATIVE_APP_SERVLET, urldata: jsonData)
        } catch {
            NSLog("json error")
        }

}
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters


            if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                if locationManager.respondsToSelector(#selector(CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
                    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                }
                else {
                    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                }

            }


        NSLog("Started to monitor the significant location Changes")
    locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
   // NSLog("the distance filter of the location manager is \(locationManager.distanceFilter)")
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating your location manager and requesting location access?

Comment: I edited the question @Paulw11